# Macros argument order matters?

Tags: c++, macros

When i compile the below program following error is generated by the compiler.

```
example.cpp:12:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'const char *')
cout << JMP(to_string(10)) << endl;

        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
example.cpp:6:34: note: expanded from macro 'JMP'
#define JMP(add) "DEFAULT is : " + DEFAULT + " JMP is : " + add

           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define DEFAULT "00000"
#define JMP(add) "DEFAULT is : " + DEFAULT + " JMP is : " + add

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << JMP(to_string(10)) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Whereas the below program compiles properly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define DEFAULT "00000"
#define JMP(add) "JMP is : " + add + "DEFAULT is : " + DEFAULT

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << JMP(to_string(10)) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Why the order of argument present in the macro body matters ?

Comment: Badly titled/asked question. You're asking why the order of macro arguments matters, but you only have a single macro argument. `DEFAULT` is not an argument to the macro, and as your macro takes only a single argument, there's no order to consider.

Comment: This is nothing to do with macros really.  Substitute out all the macros, and you'll still see the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get rid of the `+` to concatenate char array literals:

```
#define JMP(add) "DEFAULT is : " DEFAULT " JMP is : " add
```

**NOTE:**
Since `add` will expand to a `std::string` value (`to_string(10)`) from your sample, this won't work either. You'll need to call the macro like this:

```
cout << JMP("10") << endl;
```

An alternate solution would be making the parts `std::string` instances:

```
#define JMP(add) std::string("DEFAULT is : " DEFAULT " JMP is : ") + add
```

Comment: `to_string` returns a `std::string`

Comment: @mah THX for pointing out, I've been looking at the very 1st error message only.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ np, though personally I would have suggested the macro be `"DEFAULT is : " << DEFAULT << " JMP is : " << add` I think.

Comment: @mah I personally think about discouraging the use of a macro at all in favor of a little template function. But since the question was about macro problems ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the operands given to the binary expression (i.e. `+ operator`) are not of expected types. This operator is expecting a `const string &` (or a `string &` using C++ 11) for at least one of its operands. That plus left to right evaluation is why it works when you switch the order.

```
cout << to_string(10) + " is the JUMP" << endl; // having valid operands, + operator returns a string object
cout << "JUMP is : " + to_string(10) << endl;   // same here
cout << "DEFAULT is : " + "00000" << endl;      // no bueno: both operands are const char pointers
```

Provided that you have a `const string &` as a *starter**, you can keep concatenating `const char *`s all day long:

```
cout << "JUMP is : " + to_string(10) + " DEFAULT is : " + "00000" + "game is " + "concentration, " + "category is " + "..." << endl;
```

So, this actually is not about order of macro arguments but about strings, char pointers, concatenation, associativity, and operators.

*as in a sports game.